# What is the course of actions when elected moderators lock and close questions with unjustified reasons?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, moderation, contact

What should be my course of actions when elected moderators (specifically "Stack Overflow in Russian") unjustifiably lock and close questions on the Meta?

I realize, that deciding what is justified and what is not might be my personal opinion, but this is why I'm in need for a higher authority here.

I have checked through the "Contact us" but could not find a relevant topic. I'm also not eager to use the ruSO "Contact Us" form, since it is likely leading to the same moderators who mistreated the rules in the first place.

---

For anyone interested, here's the ruSO topic on the matter, from which I'm trying to escalate the issue: [Вопрос, не являющийся дубликатом, закрыт как дубликат](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11567). TLDR in Eng:

Question #1 ([Сообщество уже больше полугода поддерживает откровенный оффтопик. Доколе?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10370)) goes like "Why does ruSO supports these offtopic competition-like questions which do not have a clear rules set and are largely violating SO policy on questions guidelines" - was closed as "Offtopic" itself (ironically). Not looking at the issue presented - it is clearly a wrong moderator action, to lock the question on Meta that is aimed at discussing the rules and finding a right solution - that's one of the Meta goals after all.

Question #2 ([Вопрос, соответствующий тематике Меты, заблокирован как «не соответствует тематике»](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11435)) goes like "Why is ontopic question was locked as offtopic?" - was closed as "Duplicate of the above question". Now this is wrong once again - these are different questions, but the moderators acted nonetheless. I have casted my "re-open" vote, of course.

P.S. Let me know if I have missed something or need more details to add.

Comment: For English-only readers here's a [Google Translated](https://ru-meta-stackoverflow-com.translate.goog/questions/10370/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%84%d1%84%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%94%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-GB&_x_tr_pto=ajax,nv) version.

Answer (score 6):

The "Contact Us" doesn't go to the site moderators - it goes to the community moderation team, effectively bypassing the on-site moderation team.

Use that in this instance. You will at least get an unbiased response to your request.

Comment: "*You will at least get an unbiased response to your request.*" citation needed.